# Error 1111: mysql on trigger from insert

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1111

I am trying to understand why this trigger keeps giving me an error about invalid use of grouped function when i try to run a basin insert statement to test this out.

I have tried working with this to figure out what i am doing wrong but the error just remains the same. Error 1111

```
DROP TRIGGER a_num;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER a_num BEFORE INSERT ON test_a

  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE last INT DEFAULT 0;
INSERT INTO test_b SET full_name = CONCAT_WS(' ', NEW.f_name, NEW.l_name);
SET last = COUNT(id);
UPDATE test_b SET number = CONCAT_WS('-',  last, LEFT(NEW.f_name, 2), LEFT(NEW.f_name, 2)) WHERE id = last;
END;
//
```

Please don't mind the use or poor construction I quite a newb.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be -

```
DROP TRIGGER a_num;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER a_num BEFORE INSERT ON test_a

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE last INT DEFAULT 0;
    INSERT INTO test_b SET full_name = CONCAT_WS(' ', NEW.f_name, NEW.l_name);
    SET last = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    UPDATE test_b SET number = CONCAT_WS('-',  last, LEFT(NEW.f_name, 2), LEFT(NEW.f_name, 2)) WHERE id = last;
END;
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the CREATE statement for test_a and the INSERT statement you're using?

In MySQL Workbench if you right click on test_a go to Copy to Clipboard..Create Statement, will send the table definition.

Is there a reason you're inserting and then updating the same record?  Could you combine this into one insert?